# How can I extract, or test, the last field from a string?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a bash script to test some data.  I created a variable to hold the output of a SQL statement:

```
$ declare -p data_ck
declare -- data_ck="2019-02-17  TRUE    2019-02-10  23"
```

I presume my ***data_ck*** variable is really just a string rather than an array I can parse into fields.  So, I next figured out this syntax: `echo ${data_ck[@]:27:2}`

which returns "23" in this case.

I could also use:  `echo "${data_ck[@]: -2:2}"`

I want to determine whether my last element, 23, is equal to 30.  I have tried different variations of this statement, without success:

```
If [ ${data_ck[@]:27:2} != 30 ]; then echo "missing dates"
```

which returns:
   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

I get the same result using this method:

```
If [ ${data_ck[@]:27:2} -ne 30 ]; then echo "missing dates" fi
```

I am only slightly familiar with scripting & do not understand what I am doing wrong.  Can someone lend a hand?  Thank you!

Comment: `data_ck` is an array. Really, almost every variable in bash holds a string. Please post the output of `declare -p data_ck`. You miss `;` before `fi`, ie. `if ...; then .... ; fi`. And remember to `of [ "${....}"` quote variables.

Comment: "declare -p data_ck" returns:
declare -- data_ck="2019-02-17 TRUE 2019-02-10 23"

And, adding a semi-colon before my "fi" statement works!

Comment: @KamilCuk `data_ck` was *not* an array, confirmed by `declare -p`. You can use array syntax with a regular variable, and it will be treated as a single-element array with a value at index 0.

Comment: ${data_ck[@]:27:2} give nothing. To get 23 you must use ${data_ck[@]:3:2} see man bash : Parameter Expansion ${parameter:offset:length} If  parameter  is  @ ...

Comment: Are you actually using `If`, with an uppercase `I`? It has to be lowercase.

Comment: Why are you using `[@]` at all if your content isn't an array? It's array-specific syntax; with non-array values, the only thing it does is confuse the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data_ck` is a scalar variable, not an array, based on the
result of `delcare -p data_ck`, you can just say:

```
data_ck="2019-02-17 TRUE 2019-02-10 23"
if [[ ${data_ck: -2:2} != 30 ]]; then
    echo "missing dates"
fi
```

The following still works but is mostly superfluous:

```
if [[ ${data_ck[@]: -2:2} != 30 ]]; then
    echo "missing dates"
fi
```

As @chepner points out, `${data_ck[@]}` here is evaluated as
`${data_ck[0]}` and is equivalent to `$data_ck` in the context.

Answer (score 2):

```
set -x
declare -- data_ck="2019-02-17  TRUE    2019-02-10  23"
last_field=${data_ck##*[[:space:]]}
[[ $last_field = 30 ]]
```

...properly emits:

```
+ [[ 23 = 30 ]]
```

...which tells us that `${data_ck##*[[:space:]]}` successfully removed everything up to the last field, allowing the field's contents to be compared to `30` as per your specification.

It did this as a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), matching and removing the longest-possible string that ends in a space. (`*[[:space:]]` is a [glob-style pattern](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) matching any string ending with a space; `${var##pattern}` expands to the contents of `$var` with the longest possible match for `pattern` removed from the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

I can not see all variations of data_ck. It could be

```
data_ck=( 2019-02-17 TRUE 2019-02-10 23 )
data_ck=( 2019-02-17 FALSE 2019-02-10 23 )
data_ck=( 2019-02-17 TRUE 2019-02-10 301233 0 )
data_ck=( "2019-02-17 TRUE 2019-02-10 23" )
```

The value FALSE and the third example makes it impossible to use some fixed offset after converting the array to a string.
You can extract the fourth field with

```
if [ "${data_ck[@]:3:1}" = "23" ]; then echo "23 found"; fi
# or shorter
if [ "${data_ck[3]}" = "23" ]; then echo "23 found"; fi
```

EDIT:
When data_ck is a string, you still need to think what is the best way to het your field. Some possibilities:

```
echo "${data_ck}" | sed 's/.* //'    # Get everything after last space
echo "${data_ck}" | sed -r 's/.* ([^ ]+) */\1/' # get last field in string ending with spaces
echo "${data_ck}" | cut -d" " -f4    # Get 4th field
echo "${data_ck}" | awk '{print $4}' # 4th field where 2 spaces count as 1 delimiter
```

Comment: The way I understand this, is I could use [@]:3:1 or [3] if my variable was truly an array.  However, it is not an array - it is simply a long string.  That's why I used the "character position", meaning [@]:27:2.

Comment: @CarCrazyBen The `[@]` (and `[1]` etc) are used to control which elements of an array are fetched. Do **not** use them with non-array variables. At best, they'll be ignored (but confuse anyone trying to read/maintain the script); at worst, they'll make the script fail in unpredictable ways.